# what is the '¬' character called and what is it for

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, autohotkey

I do not ever think I have ever had a need to type this character `"¬"`, and so I was wondering what it is called and what it is for and why it is on the my keyboards (both my UK and EU keyboards)? I assume that it had some common function back in the 1970's maybe, but I'm curious what that might be as I'm almost completely certain that I have never once in over 25 years ever had a need to type this character for anything. I *do* use the tilde character `` "`" `` a lot, but never the shift-variant on that key of the `"¬"`.

Part of the reason that I am asking this is that I might use it as an AutoHotkey trigger, since it seems so completely useless to me, but I was curious about what it might be for etc before I do that.

Comment: It's used in Math and logic. Not in programming(hard to type, maybe? Easier if you use `~` or `!`, same thing)

Comment: `\`` is called a [backtick](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick), a tilde looks like `~`.

Answer (score 8):

It's the logic negation symbol.

It's used in some programming languages as a mean to negate a boolean value, particulary old languages

Comment: Interesting, come to think of it, that does sort of sound like something I might have heard in the distant past, but, I use bash, python, C#, PowerShell, AutoHotkey and a few other languages and I've never seen this used. hmm, maybe it's used in something ancient like Fortran. Great, I think I can safely use this for other purposes then, thanks! 

Comment: What's also pretty interesting that this symbol is not anywhere on US keyboards. If we're talking about the same backtick key  in the upper left (under `Esc`), the secondary symbol on ours is a tilde (`~`). Do you not have this key across the pond?

Comment: @YorSubs Generally programming languages don't use it as it's not on US keyboards nor in ASCII. However, when writing out logical expressions it is used: `¬(x∧y)` means NOT (x AND y); in programming this would (generally) be written as `!(x && y).`

Comment: Yup, it's used a lot in AI-based systems when we are building a knowledge base where we need to evaluate rules based on Predicates.

Comment: I see this `¬` symbol in Coq Programming Language (Proof Assistant), it's the the logical negation operator there too! There, `¬ P` reads as "not P".

Comment: I can type it on my MacBook keyboard with ⌥⇧N.
On windows, it can be typed as any ascii symbol with typing it's code while pressing left Alt, in this particular case the [Extended ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is 172, so that: press down left Alt, in numpad keyboard type three digits: 1, 7, 2, then release left Alt.

Answer (score 4):

The ¬ character is also used in AppleScript to force a long line of code to break onto the next line. On a French Mac keyboard, you get it with Option (alt) "L", which has a kind of logic to it :)